# return complete document with array containing satisfying condition in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm really stuck in this problem tried everything using aggregation and projection but no luck yet, please help me figure out some optimal way to do it so,

this is how my document look like

```
  {
  engagement: {
    loves: [ 5e87a316457e874ce886356c,5e87a316457e874ce886356d, 5e87a316457e874ce886356e, 5e87a316457e874ce886356f],
    loveCount: 4,
  },
  _id: 5e87c097c9374e6628a499b
}
```

Now i want to provide an element of loves array and based on that it will produce following result

element: 5e87a316457e874ce886356d

result

```
  {
  engagement: {
    loves: [ 5e87a316457e874ce886356d],
    loveCount: 4,
  },
  _id: 5e87c097c9374e6628a499b
}
```

element: XYZABC

result

```
  {
  engagement: {
    loves: [],
    loveCount: 4,
  },
  _id: 5e87c097c9374e6628a499b
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "engagement.loves": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$engagement.loves",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$$this", "5e87a316457e874ce886356d" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zpb4KvHRx_1)

Comment: oh thank you so much but i how can i add multiple arrays to be filtered in this senerio, like one filter for loves one for favorite with the same logic

Comment: @Sundeep that's not a problem - you can add more statements like `engagement.favorites` etc..